# Is Quantum Entanglement the one-dimensional spatial relationship between two particles as described by mathematics?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

Is Quantum Entanglement the one-dimensional spatial relationship between two particles as described by mathematics?

By one dimensional I mean, when they travel at opposite directions their spin is also opposite (without any spooky communication between the two, just the plain fact of their direction as described by our observations).

Comment: I am a noob in Quantum Computing so if you thing this question is somewhat irrelevant (more of a physics question), offsetting, already put and answered or wrongly put, please reply as soon as you can.

Comment: Maybe only when the direction of the movement of each particle is opposite can we speak of entanglement or, maybe better formulated, ideal entanglement.

Comment: Hi @petpet and welcome to the Quantum Computing SE :). In most of the quantum hardware systems, the entanglement is not related to the qubit movement direction just because they are always fixed in their positions.

Comment: or the aproximation of an 180 degrees angle

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean about a 180-degree angle. But I also want to mention: The entanglement is not only about two qubits, but entanglement can be also between three or more qubits. In this case, if we will take them and throw in random directions, the correlation will still exist no matter in what directions we throw them.

Comment: the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. "Entanglement" is a property that a bipartite system can have. It's not necessarily related to a spatial separation of particles (although it often is). It's not an additional axis, or something that has a "dimension" like you seem to writing

Comment: Hi  Davit Khachatryan, thank you for the warm welcome. I understand that qubits stay put in a quantum hardware system. I used the movement example in order to express my question as I am neither a physisist nor a mathematician or computer scientist. My goal is to understand Entanglement realy and not necessarily qubits authough it seems hopeless to try to understand the one without the other.

Comment: With the angle of a straight line I tried to justify why I think that Entaglement is only a model of understanding and does not actually exist. So in Entaglement as far as I understand one particle is the mirror image of the other and in a three dimensional space the most perfect mirror image happens when the two spins (z axis and its polarity) are perpenducular to a common axis (1 dimensional number line). This is what I ment with the 180 degrees angle.

Comment: When you say entagnglement between more than two qubits, you mean a bipartite correlation of two groups of qubits or an entaglement that is expressed geometricaly in a square or triangle like a network? Thank for your answer and references.

Comment: Hi glS, as I mentioned above I am not a proffesional in the field so my question may no make whole lot of sense as you put it. I understand that Entanglement is a bipartite property but how on earth is Entanglement not related to spatial separation of particles? I mean is not spatial separation necessary to speak of two distinct particles, hence bipartite? Also with dimension, as it is generaly a very ambiguous term, I mean the way we understand the Property of Entanglement in space, or geometricaly and more intuitive

Comment: . I am not saying that Entanglement is an axis or that it nesseseraly needs a spatial description to be understood, although it does for me and maybe for other people who want this kind of understanding on this phenomenon.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity and thank you for your edits.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have studied Architecture and Applied Arts, in particular Sound Synthesis and Installation Design, in Universities and now I am studying Fine Arts. I posted this question in order to validate and share my thoughts uppon an important concept in computing as I work a lot with computers and care about their future. Also this concept has in my opinions many other applications like for instance Psychology (fellow students) as well as the Arts.

Comment: About 3 or more entangled particles: here is an example state $| \uparrow \rangle | \downarrow \rangle | \uparrow \rangle + | \downarrow \rangle | \uparrow  \rangle | \downarrow \rangle$, so if the first particle measured in $| \uparrow \rangle$ state the second particle is in $| \downarrow \rangle$ and third one $| \uparrow \rangle$ states deterministically, and if the first one is $| \downarrow \rangle$ the second particle is in $| \downarrow \rangle$ and third one is in $| \uparrow \rangle$ states deterministically. Their states are not separable and thus are correlated.

Comment: In classical mechanics, the state of the particle can be given by its position and velocity. Two classical particles are given with separate positions and velocities ($x_1$, $v_1$ and $x_2$, $v_2$). In quantum mechanics, the state of the particles is given by a wavefunction. For two particles there exist states that can't be described by separate wavefunctions of each particle, but can be described by one joint wavefunction. These states are the entangled states.

Comment: More philosophical :). In physics, we believe in experiments and we use those theories that can explain the experiments. Quantum physics was and is a good tool/model that describes the quantum experiments, so we continue to use the "imagination/mathematical description" that it provides us. The only thing that exists is the experiments the rest is just our imagination that in some sense can or can not have some correlations with reality.

Comment: @petpet note that you need to tag people in a comment for them to be notified by your comment. A system being "bipartite" refers to it having more than one degree of freedom. The polarisation of spatially separated particles is a common example of this, but you can have a bipartite state composed of different degrees of freedom of a single particle, e.g. position and polarisation of a single photon. E.g. a single photon's state $|H,\text{left}\rangle+|V,\text{right}\rangle$ is entangled. As I was saying, spatial separation of particles is usually involved, but it's not a fundamental feature

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan I got it, gIS I understand.

Answer (score 2):

A qubit is a two-level quantum system and these two-levels in some hardware can be implemented by spins of the electron, but it's not the only option (can be just two "stabile" quantum states not essentially associated with spins). In this sense it is not only about the spin (directional) correlation between qubits, it's about state correlation between them. But suppose that we have spin qubits: two quantum levels are two spin directions (up or down) in some chosen direction. An example of an entangled state for two qubits:

$$| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( | \downarrow_z \rangle| \downarrow_z \rangle + | \uparrow_z \rangle| \uparrow_z \rangle \right)$$

This means that if we will do a measurement of spin in the z-direction we will always measure both qubits down or up (nice explanation of the entanglement 2:50 - 4:15 of Anton Zeilinger's [presentation](https://youtu.be/TrsnMNh9W9U?t=170)). But not only this. A valid question is what is our $|\psi\rangle$ state expressed by spin up and down states in x-direction. In other words what will be the measurement results, if we measure the spin in the x-direction. Note that (video [lecture](https://youtu.be/Rc1vFAUnRUM?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61-9PEhRognw5vryrSEVLPr&t=2865) by Allan Adams about spin: especially from 47:45-52:45):

\begin{align*} 
| \uparrow_z \rangle =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( | \uparrow_x \rangle + | \downarrow_x \rangle \right)
\qquad
| \downarrow_z \rangle =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( | \uparrow_x \rangle - | \downarrow_x \rangle \right)
\end{align*}

That's why:

$$| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( | \downarrow_x \rangle| \downarrow_x \rangle + | \uparrow_x \rangle| \uparrow_x \rangle \right)$$

So, if we will measure in x-direction we will still have a correlation between the $| \uparrow_x \rangle$ and $| \downarrow_x \rangle$ measurement results of two entangled qubits. The same is true for y-direction. Thus, this is not only about a one-dimensional correlation. And, it is not about where are physically our qubits: they can be in a fixed position, they can be at some distance and no matter what the measurement results should be the same.

For more, I highly recommend this [lecture](https://youtu.be/awpnsGl08bc?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61-9PEhRognw5vryrSEVLPr&t=1713) by Allan Adams (about separable states and entangled states from 28:33-36:02) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuvK-od647c) from Veritasium youtube channel.